# Why do I need 2 __str__ methods to print?

Tags: python, oop

The `AddressBook` class finds uses regex to find a string that matches the pattern, which is a name.

`self.contacts` loops through the `Contact` class and prints out the pattern in a dictionary format

```
import re
import sys


class Contact(object):

    def __init__(self, match):
        for key, value in match.groupdict().items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(
            sorted(
                ["\t{}: {}".format(key, val) for key, val in self.__dict__.items()]))


class AddressBook(object):

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.names_file = open(filename, encoding="utf-8")
        self.data = self.names_file.read()
        self.names_file.close()
        line = re.compile('(?P<name>^([A-Z][a-z]*((\s)))+[A-Z][a-z]*$)')
        self.contacts = [Contact(match) for match in line.finditer(self.data)]

address_book = AddressBook('contacts.txt')
print (address_book)
```

This will give me a python object:

```
<__main__.AddressBook object at 0x0338E410>
```

But if I add another `__str__`method like this...

```
import re
import sys


class Contact(object):
    ... #same code as above


class AddressBook(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.names_file = open(filename, encoding="utf-8")
        self.data = self.names_file.read()
        self.names_file.close()
        line = re.compile('(?P<name>^([A-Z][a-z]*((\s)))+[A-Z][a-z]*$)')
        self.contacts = [Contact(match) for match in line.finditer(self.data)]

    def __str__(self):
       return '\n'.join('{}'.format(i) for i in self.contacts)

address_book = AddressBook('contacts.txt')
print (address_book)
```

It actually prints it out:

```
name: Rick James
name: Charlie Murphy
name: Prince
```

My question is why does it give me a python object even though I have a `__str__` method in the `Contact` class?

Comment: Because you're printing an `AddressBook`, not a `Contact`?

Comment: Is there another way to do this without having to resort to 2 `__str__` methods?

Comment: @bLunt You can do all the work in the `AddressBook.__str__()` method and format all the `Contact` instances it contains there, but it's probably better to keep the logic in the two `__str__()` methods - let each object be responsible of its own readable representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that print() uses the instance's `__str__()` method, which by default uses the object's `__repr__()` method. Now, your second example overrides the inherited `__str__()` method, giving you a nice output you wanted.

The following example illustrates this behavior:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     x = 42
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> print(f)
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7fb12d4c6890>
>>> class Foo2:
...     x = 42
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'x = {}'.format(self.x)
... 
>>> f2 = Foo2()
>>> print(f2)
x = 42
```

For more information about the differences between `__str__()` and `__repr__()` you can also [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python), a very good and exhaustive explanation.

Comment: That's a good link, but the best answer may be deeply hidden. :)

Comment: You have a point here. :) Though the link was meant more as a _"further reading"_ resource for a curious reader than anything else, I wanted to spare OP the potentially unnecessary details, just described the core mechanism behind the observed behavior. :)